# How can I terminate a loop for input if I don't know the number of lines beforehand?

Tags: java, loops, infinite-loop

How can I terminate a loop for input if I  don't know the number of lines beforehand?

2015-08, 2016-04

2015-08-15, clicks, 635 
2016-03-24, app_installs, 683
2015-04-05, favorites, 763
2016-01-22, favorites, 788
2015-12-26, clicks, 525
2016-06-03, retweets, 101
2015-12-02, app_installs, 982
2016-09-17, app_installs, 770
2015-11-07, impressions, 245
2016-10-16, impressions, 567

---

I have tried this
`while (reader.hasNextLine())` but it is expecting another input.

Comment: `if (shouldBreak) break;` doesn't work?

Comment: How do you know when the input has finished? If you have no idea, you can't code it.

Comment: Can you share your code? It's very hard to help you without some context.

Comment: When do you want your loop to stop, then? I wouldn’t trust your Java program to read the mind of the user, so you may have the user enter “end” or some other agreed-upon input when there is no more input. Your program may compare the actual input to the stop word and break out if it’s equal.

Answer (score 0):

You can break any loop in java using `break` keyword, in case of `while` loop:

```
while((reader.hasNextLine()) {
   boolean shouldBreak = ... // your code when it should break
   if (shouldBreak) break;

}
// here the execution will go after the loop
```

The `break` can be used in any loop like for/while/do.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(true) { //or any other condition
    //do something
    if (userInput.equals("&") {
        break;
    }
}
```

`break` keyword can be used for immediate stopping and escaping the loop. It is used in most of programming languages.
There is also one useful keyword to slightly influence loop processing: `continue`. It immediately jumps to the next iteration.

**Examples**:

```
int i = 0;
while (true) {
    if (i == 4) {
        break;
    }
    System.out.println(i++);
}
```

will print:

```
0
1
2
3
```

Continue:

```
int i = 0;
while (true) {
    if (i == 4) {
        i++;
        continue;
    }
    if (i == 6) {
        break;
    }
    System.out.println(i++);
}
```

will print:

```
0
1
2
3
5
```

Comment: The input is as above. There is no additional character after last line.

Comment: @AzatDjanybekov is it input from file? If yes, you'll have EOF character

Comment: This input is from stdin.